# Is it possible to set a WPF ListBoxItem's background to a hex color stored as a string inside an objects property?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

If I have a simple object like:

```
public class person
{
    string name;
    string color;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Where the color is formatted as #FFFFFF in a string.  Is there a way in either code behind or XAML to set each individual items background color to the color stored in the person object?  I'm setting the listbox's itemsource to a List:

```
ListBox.ItemsSource = listofpeople;
```

At this point I've tried iterating through the ListBox.items collection but that seems to just return the underlying "person" objects but not the ListBoxItem objects that I'm *guessing* I need to edit the background property?  Is this even possible in code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an appropriate ItemContainerStyle.

The Binding `Background="{Binding Color}"` works because there is built-in automatic type conversion from `string` to `Brush`.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The Person class must declare public properties:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```